# Reference: Continuity of Eigenvectors

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am looking for an appropriate reference for the following fact. I already posted on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133071/reference-continuity-of-eigenvectors), but got no answer.

> For each $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}_{\text{sym}}$ (symmetric matrix),
>   there exist $\varepsilon, L > 0$, such that
>   for all $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}_{\text{sym}}$ with $\|H\| \le \varepsilon$
>   the following holds:
>
> There are orthogonal matrices $P, Q$, such that
>   \begin{equation*}
>  Q^\top \, X \, Q = \Lambda(X)
> \end{equation*}
>   and
>   \begin{equation*}
>  P^\top \, (X + H) \, P = \Lambda(X + H)
> \end{equation*}
>   and
>   \begin{equation*}
>  \| P - Q \| \le L \, \| H \|.
> \end{equation*}

Here, $\Lambda(X)$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $X$.
That is, $P$ and $Q$ are bases of eigenvectors of $X$ and $X + H$, respectively.
Here, it is crucial that we can choose $Q$ in dependence of $H$.

This result can be found in 
[this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036142901393814), see Lemma 4.3.
I feel, however, that a reference from 2003 is not appropriate for this "simple" fact.

Comment: I will answer your question on MSE. So I will also vote to close this version here.

Comment: You may also like to check Kato's "Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators", especially the chapter on finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been answered already on Math.SE.